Display DGV header text at page break in Word
I export the data from DGV to Word with the code:
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim oTable As Word.Table = objDoc.Tables.Add(objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range,
Datagridview2.RowCount, Datagridview2.ColumnCount, Datagridview2.ColumnHeadersVisible = 
True)

For r = 0 To Datagridview2.RowCount - 2
    For c = 0 To Datagridview2.Columns.Count - 1
        If Datagridview2.Rows(r).Cells(4).Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            sum += Datagridview2.Rows(r).Cells(4).Value
End If
objDoc.Tables(1).Cell(r + 1, c + 1).Range.Text = Datagridview2(c, r).FormattedValue

Next
Next

When " Datagridview2.ColumnHeadersVisible = True " the DGV is exported but without header text.
How do I get the header text displayed in Word from the DGV even with a page break? .
Greetings
Andi
